# Will my prayer mat become impure by washing it together with clothes that have sperm on them?

Tags: taharah, clothing, najis

I washed my prayer mat (janemaz) with an article of clothing having sperm on it. Will the prayer mat become impure?

Comment: Salam and welcome on Islam SE. Please consider taking your time to learn more about our site and model by taking the [tour] and visiting the [help]. Sperms are not even considered as impure based on strong ahadith, yes it is a discussed matter among scholars, but note that sun, water and soil are considered as mediums to purify things.

Comment: I assume you mean washing it in a washing machine.